# Why is PHP not sending form scores to PHP MyAdmin database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, forms

I am a beginner at web development, and for a college project website I have created a form in HTML with some radio button questions, and then JavaScript which will check the answers against the correct answers, and send an alert with the score out of 10. I have created this with the help of ChatGPT, as I do not really know anything about JavaScript, but I can work out what the JS does as I can program in python, so its sort of similar.

```
    <script>
        document.getElementById("quizForm").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
            checkQuiz(event);
        });

        function checkQuiz(event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting

            // Get selected answers
            const answers = {
                q1: document.querySelector('input[name="q1"]:checked'),
                q2: document.querySelector('input[name="q2"]:checked'),
                q3: document.querySelector('input[name="q3"]:checked'),
                q4: document.querySelector('input[name="q4"]:checked'),
                q5: document.querySelector('input[name="q5"]:checked'),
                q6: document.querySelector('input[name="q6"]:checked'),
                q7: document.querySelector('input[name="q7"]:checked'),
                q8: document.querySelector('input[name="q8"]:checked'),
                q9: document.querySelector('input[name="q9"]:checked'),
                q10: document.querySelector('input[name="q10"]:checked'),

            };

            // Check if all questions are answered
            if (Object.values(answers).every(answer => answer !== null)) {
                // Check correct answers (Modify as needed)
                const correctAnswers = { 
                    q1: 'A',
                    q2: 'D',
                    q3: 'A',
                    q4: 'D',
                    q5: 'C',
                    q6: 'D',
                    q7: 'A',
                    q8: 'C',
                    q9: 'A',
                    q10: 'C'
                };

                let score = 0;

                // Check each answer
                for (const question in answers) {
                    if (answers[question].value === correctAnswers[question]) {
                        score++;
                    }
                }

                // Display the score (Modify as needed)
                alert(`You scored ${score}/10!`);
 
                //Set the value of the hiddent input field to the score               
                document.getElementById("quizScore").value = score;


            } else {
                alert('Please answer all questions before submitting.');
            }
        }
    
    </script>
```

The JavaScript will also set the score to a hidden input on the form with a value `quizScore` which will then be picked up by the PHP in order to send the score to the database.

The PHP will then grab the username from another table, and should then send the username and score into their respective columns in the 'score' table, adding onto existing scores, and creating a new entry if the user does not already have one.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

session_start(); 
$loggedin = isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) ? $_SESSION['loggedin'] : false;

//Create variable for different values
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "gibjohn";

//Create a connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

//Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed; " . $conn->connect_error);
}

//Define the query to select the email and username from the users table where the email matches a parameter
$query = "SELECT email, username FROM users WHERE email = ?";
//Prepare the query for execution
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
//Bind the value of the 'name' session variable (email of the user) to the parameter '?' in the query
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_SESSION['name']);
//Execute the prepared statement
$stmt->execute();
//Get the result set from the executed statement
$result = $stmt->get_result();
//Fetch the result set in an associative array, containing the email and username of the user with the specified email
$rt = $result->fetch_assoc();

if ($rt) {
    //Retrieve the username from the fetched array and store it in '$uname'
    $uname = $rt['username'];
} else {
    //handle the case where $rt is not set
    echo "Error: User not found";
}


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    //Retrieve quiz score from post data
    $quizScore = $_POST["quizScore"];

    // Check if the user already has a score in the database
    $query = "SELECT score FROM scores WHERE username = ?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $uname);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $existingScore = $result->fetch_assoc();

    // If the user already has a score, update it; otherwise, insert a new score
    if ($existingScore) {
        $newScore = $existingScore['score'] + $quizScore;
        $query = "UPDATE scores SET score = ? WHERE username = ?";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param("is", $newScore, $uname);
        $stmt->execute();
        if ($stmt->affected_rows > 0) {
            echo "Quiz score updated successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $stmt->error;
        }
    } else {
        // If the user doesn't have a score, insert a new score
        $query = "INSERT INTO scores (username, score) VALUES (?, ?)";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param("si", $uname, $quizScore);
        $stmt->execute();
        if ($stmt->affected_rows > 0) {
            echo "Quiz score inserted successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $stmt->error;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

On clicking submit on the form, the JS works fine in terms of working out the score, and will show the alert and give the user a score out of 10, however it either doesnt submit the form and let the PHP do its thing, or it tries and the PHP does nothing, but I dont know what is going wrong, and how to find out. All it does is show the form, and then doesnt even reload the page so the answers are still seected. Is the stuff ChatGPT gave me ok, or has it messed everything up?

I have tried removing a manual page reload in JS, as ChatGPT said this could not give the form enough chance to submit, I have made sure the form is using the POST method, I have PHP outputting if it is successful or not etc, printing out errors, but it shows nothing which makes me think its not even running.

Comment: This is not something I expect in a question: _"Is the stuff ChatGPT gave me ok, or has it messed everything up?"_. It's a clear sign you didn't put in any effort yourself to understand the code. Start with that.

Comment: *"it [...] doesnt submit the form"* - That's exactly what `event.preventDefault();` does, and the comment on that line seems to imply that this is intentional.  It's not clear to me why you're surprised that the form isn't submitting when you're explicitly preventing it from submitting.

Comment: Hint: chatGPT can't teach you to program, or remove the need for you to have some idea what you're doing. It can only make suggestions, and will make mistakes pretty often. Don't ask it to write something you won't be able to verify afterwards (this advice is applicable to anything you ask it to do, not just writing code). It's a time-saver, not a substitute

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to web development with JS and PHP. To complete your task chatGPT might be helpful, but if you really want to learn JS, better start with the fundamentals instead of generating code... anyway, here comes the solution:

The first line in your `check Answers` function stops the Form submit event. That's OK so far, because you want to run some Javascript first.

What you want to add, is some code that actually submits the Form, let's say after the user has confirmed/closed the dialog with the results. A convenient method to do so with vanilla Javascript is [requestSubmit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/requestSubmit).

To not overcomplicate this, I suggest that you create a second form that contains just the hidden field.

`alert()` is a blocking function, so you can simply put the call to requestSubmit after it (and after setting the hidden input value), so it will be executed when the user closes the dialog.

```
alert('You scored...'); 
// set hidden field in separate form
// ...

// submit the hidden form
var form = document.getElementById("hiddenForm");
form.requestSubmit();
```